# Standalone exe file Python without Python installed

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller, exe

I am trying to create executable file from Python script with **os**, **tkiner**, **pandas** and **xlsxwriter** packages. I used pyinstaller, but always get error that pandas is not found.
How to create exe file with these packages that will work on machine that does not have Python installed at all?

Answer (score 0):

For that is pretty simple

Just use:

```
Pyinstaller —onefile -icon=myicon.ico -—windowed myscript.py
```

Well that’s it.

Note: using —-windowed so the console won’t show up